# Which files other than .jar needed for making an installer

Tags: java, jar, installation

I had completed building a .jar file for me project (media player), it is also running successfully with command line `java -jar mediaplayer.jar`.

But now i need to make an installer, so what all files do I need for making an installer, do i need to bundle the lib files also with the installer.

also when i launch my .jar file with Java Web Start, it says "Unable to launch application"

Comment: *"also when i launch my .jar file with Java Web Start, it says "Unable to launch application""*  You are doing something wrong.   What are the details of the failure?  JWS is a very good option for deploying Java desktop apps.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i dropped the idea for javaWS,instead i want to make an installer,what all files do i need with my .jar file. do i need the lib files also to bundle with jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need to bundle both your `mediaplayer.jar` and the libraries in your classpath. You will also need to generate a native executable file that will at least do `java -jar mediaplayer.jar`.

Usually native launchers also check if Java is installed on the target machine and help user to install it if it is not.